# Does the following series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge?

$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n\pi)^2}{1+n\pi} \big(a_n\sin(n\pi x) -  b_n\cos(n\pi x) \big)^2$

where $a_n= \displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\sin(n x)dx$ and $b_n= \displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(n x)dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\;x=0\;$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2\pi^2}{1+n\pi}b_n^2$$

so unless $\;b_n\;$ is, for example,  a sequence converging to zero pretty quick (at least as fast as $\;\frac1{n^{1+\epsilon}}\;$ , for some $\;\epsilon>0\,$) , the sum diverges.

Meaning: without knowing what the $\;a_n,\,b_n\;$ are, one can't say much about this series.

Comment: Thank you for your response, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the  Fourier coefficients.

Comment: @lewa That's what I thought...though whose Fourier series I can't say

Comment: I have edited the question, i would be grateful if you take a look, now.

Comment: @lewa This question's already an accepted answer. I recommend you to post a new question...but I see the answer will be very similar to the one given above.